# How to generate string with a char repeated for n times?

Tags: awk

I can use the following code to generate a string.

```
$ awk -e 'BEGIN { for(i=1;i<=10;++i) s = s "x"; print s }'
xxxxxxxxxx
```

But its complexity is super-linear wrt the string length.

```
$ time awk -e 'BEGIN { for(i=1;i<=10000000;++i) s = s "x" }'

real    0m0.868s
user    0m0.857s
sys 0m0.008s
$ time awk -e 'BEGIN { for(i=1;i<=100000000;++i) s = s "x" }'

real    0m9.886s
user    0m9.801s
sys 0m0.065s
$ time awk -e 'BEGIN { for(i=1;i<=1000000000;++i) s = s "x" }'

real    1m46.074s
user    1m45.171s
sys 0m0.760s
```

Is there a better way to repeat a char n times and assign the result to a variable?

Comment: Just to point out, this is never going to be an issue in practice. How often do you even need strings of size 1000?

Comment: @chepner If the solution is good it should be good for short strings, too. I have come across similar use cases for n < 100.

Comment: @laune Not necessarily. You aren't going to use [Karatsuba's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) to multiply small numbers, and the code in this question is likely plenty fast enough even for n<=1000.

Comment: @chepner @laune : short lengths, why even bother using a loop at all :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                     
`( LC_ALL=C mawk2 'NF = (OFS = $(ORS=_) = "Ukraine")*_ + 87123' <<< ''; )  0.00s user 0.00s system 25% cpu 0.016 total`
`gnu-wc -lcm  0  609861  609861`
`UkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkraineUkrain`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sprintf` to create a string of spaces, then use `gsub` to replace each space with an `x`:

```
$  time awk  'BEGIN {s = sprintf("%*s", 100000000, ""); gsub(".", "x", s)}'

real    0m1.744s
user    0m1.645s
sys 0m0.098s
```

This can be wrapped in an `awk` function:

```
function mkStr(c, n,       s) { 
  s = sprintf("%*s", n, "");
  gsub(".", c, s);
  return s;
}
```

(`s` is a parameter simply to scope the variable to the function; it needs no argument, and indeed, any argument passed will be ignored.)

---

Update: there appears to be a significant difference in performance depending on which version of `awk` you are using. The above test used 20070501, the BSD(?) `awk` that ships with macOS. `gawk-5.1.0` takes significantly longer.

I don't know what accounts for the difference; perhaps there is a solution that is fast in both versions.

Update 2: Ed Morton (in the comments) has verified that `gsub` is responsible for the slow running time in `gawk`, could not find a workaround, and has filed a [bug report](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2021-07/msg00030.html) with the maintainers.

Comment: don't gsub 100-mil - that's gonna be slow no matter what. `gsub( )` the length-square-rooted version of that string, then square the string once.

Answer (score 4):

```
function loop(n){
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++) s = s "x";
        return s;
}

function repl(n){
        s = sprintf("%*s", n, "");
        gsub(/ /, "x", s);
    return s;
}

function recStack(n,    h){
        switch( n ){
                case 0:
                        return "";
                default:
                        if( n % 2 == 1 ){
                                h = recStack( int((n-1)/2) )
                                return h h "x";
                    } else {
                                h = recStack( int(n/2) )
                                return h h;
                        }
        }
}

function recStackIf(n,    h){
        if( n == 0 ) return "";
        if( n % 2 == 1 ){
                h = recStackIf( int((n-1)/2) ); # create first half
                return h h "x";                 # duplicate + one "x"
        } else {
                h = recStackIf( int(n/2) );  # create first half
                return h h;                  # duplicate
        }
}

function recArray(n,    h, n2){
    if( n in a ) return a[n];
        switch( n ){
                case 0:
                        return a[0] = "";
                default:
                        if( n % 2 == 1 ){
                                n2 = int((n-1)/2);
                                h = recArray( n2 );
                                return a[n] = h h "x";
                        } else {
                                n2 = int(n/2);
                                h = recArray( n2 );
                                return a[n] = h h;
                        }
        }
}

function recArrayIf(n,    h, n2){
    if( n in a ) return a[n];
        if( n == 0 ) return a[0] = "";
        if( n % 2 == 1 ){
                n2 = int((n-1)/2);
                h = recArrayIf( n2 );
                return a[n] = h h "x";
        } else {
                n2 = int(n/2);
                h = recArrayIf( n2 );
                return a[n] = h h;
        }
}


function concat(n){
    exponent = log(n)/log(2)
    m = int(exponent)                   # floor
    m += (m < exponent ? 1 : 0)         # ceiling
    s = "x"
    for (i=1; i<=m; i++) {
        s = s s
    }
    s = substr(s,1,n)
    return s
}

BEGIN {
        switch( F ){
                case "recStack":
                        xxx = recStack( 100000000 );
                        break;
                case "recStackIf":
                        xxx = recStackIf( 100000000 );
                        break;
                case "recArray":
                        xxx = recArray( 100000000 );
                        break;
                case "recArrayIf":
                        xxx = recArrayIf( 100000000 );
                        break;
                case "loop":
                        xxx = loop( 100000000 );
                        break;
                case "repl":
                        xxx = repl( 100000000 );
                        break;
                case "concat":
                        xxx = concat( 100000000 );
                        break;
        }

print length(xxx);
##      xloop = loop(100000000 );
##      if( xxx == xloop ) print "Match";
}
```

Times are:

```
# loop :            real 0m5,405s, user 0m5,243s, sys 0m0,160s
# repl :            real 0m7,670s, user 0m7,506s, sys 0m0,164s
# recArray:         real 0m0,302s, user 0m0,141s, sys   0m0,161s
# recArrayIf:       real 0m0,309s, user 0m0,168s, sys   0m0,141s
# recStack:         real 0m0,316s, user 0m0,124s, sys   0m0,192s
# recStackIf:       real 0m0,305s, user 0m0,152s, sys   0m0,152s
# concat:           real 0m0,664s, user 0m0,300s, sys   0m0,364s
```

There's not much difference between the 5 versions of binary decomposition: a bunch of heap memory is used in all cases. Having the global array hang around until the end of all times isn't good and therefore I'd prefer either stack version.

wlaun@terra:/tmp$ gawk -V
GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.2.0)
wlaun@terra:/tmp$ lscpu
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit

Note that the above timing has been done with a statement printing the resulting string's length, which adds about 0.2 s to each version. Also, /usr/bin/time isn't reliable. Here are the relative "real" values from time without the print length(xxx):

```
# loop:       0m5,248s
# repl:       0m7,705s
# recStack:   0m0,103s
# recStackIf: 0m0,097s
# recArray:   0m0,103s
# recArrayIf: 0m0,099s
# concat:     0m0,455s
```

Added on request of Ed Morton:

Why is any of the recursive functions faster than any of the linear functions that iterate over O(N) elements? (The "O(N)" is the "big oh" symbol and is used to indicate a value that is N, possibly multiplied and/or incremented by some constant. A circle's circumference is O(r), it's area is O(r²).)

The answer is simple: By dividing N by 2, we get two strings of length O(N/2). This provides the possibility of re-using the result for the first half (no matter how we obtain it) for the second half! Thus, we'll get the second half of the result for free (except for the string copy operation, which is basically a machine instruction on most popular architectures). There is no reason why this great idea should not be applied for creating the first half as well, which means that we get three quarters of the result for free (except - see above). A little overhead results from the single "x" we have to throw in to cater for odd subdivisions of N.

There are many other recursive algorithms along the idea of halving and dealing with both sections individually, the most famous of them are Binary Search and Quicksort.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a fast solution using any POSIX awk (tested on an average 8G RAM laptop running cygwin with GNU awk 5.1.0):

```
time awk -v n=100000000 'BEGIN {
    exponent = log(n)/log(2)
    m = int(exponent)                   # floor
    m += (m < exponent ? 1 : 0)         # ceiling
    s = "x"
    for (i=1; i<=m; i++) {
        s = s s
    }
    s = substr(s,1,n)
}'

real    0m0.665s
user    0m0.328s
sys     0m0.343s
```

The above just appends a copy of the string to itself until it's at least as big as the target string length and finally truncates it to exactly the desired length. The only somewhat tricky part is calculating how many times to append `s` to itself and that's just a case of solving `2^m = n` for `m` given you already know `n` (100000000 in this case), see https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/algebra/exponentsolve.php.

Obviously you could make the loop `while ( length(s) < n )` instead of calculating `m` and that'd make the script briefer but would slow it down a bit (but it'd still be pretty fast):

```
$ time awk -v n=100000000 'BEGIN{s="x"; while (length(s) < n) s=s s; s=substr(s,1,n)}'

real    0m1.072s
user    0m0.562s
sys     0m0.483s
```

[@JamesBrown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4162356/james-brown) had a better idea than calling `length()` on each iteration that also avoids having to calculate `m` while being about as fast:

```
$ time awk -v n=100000000 'BEGIN{s="x"; for (i=1; i<n; i*=2) s=s s; s=substr(s,1,n)}'

real    0m0.710s
user    0m0.281s
sys     0m0.390s
```

Originally I had the following thinking doubling strings of "x"s would be a faster approach than doubling individual "x"s on each iteration of the loop but it was a bit slower:

```
$ time awk -v n=100000000 '
    BEGIN {
        d = 1000000
        m = 7
        s = sprintf("%*s",d,"")
        gsub(/ /,"x",s)
        for (i=1; i<=m; i++) {
            s = s s
        }
        s = substr(s,1,n)
    }
'

real    0m1.030s
user    0m0.625s
sys     0m0.375s
```

The idea in that 2nd script was to generate a string long enough to be meaningful but short enough that `gsub()` can convert all blanks to "x"s quickly (which I've found to be 1000000 chars by trial and error), then just repeat the above process with fewer iterations.

I opened a bug report with the gawk providers about `gsub()` being slow for this case, see https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2021-07/msg00030.html if you're interested, but it looks like the outcome of that will just be that `gsub()` is a heavy tool, it's not surprising that it takes a long time for 100 million regexp matches, but you can speed it up considerable by setting `LC_ALL=C` before it runs so gawk doesn't have to worry about multibyte locales.

Comment: Instead of `while(length(s)<n)` you could could use `i=1; while(i<n){i*=2; s=s s}'`.

Comment: @JamesBrown Nice idea! I updated my answer to include that approach (but tweaked it to a `for` loop instead of `while` as IMHO that's slightly clearer).

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with `perl`:

```bash
# assigning to a variable
$ perl -e '$s = "x" x 10'

# printing the string
$ perl -e 'print "x" x 10'
xxxxxxxxxx
```

Note that there's no newline for the `print` in the above example, use `perl -le` if you want one.

Here's a timing comparison:

```bash
$ time perl -e '$s = "x" x 100000000'
real    0m0.071s

# script.awk is the first code from Ed Morton's answer
$ time mawk -v n=100000000 -f script.awk
real    0m0.136s

$ time gawk -v n=100000000 -f script.awk
real    0m0.429s
```

Comment: This is an awk only question.

Comment: Yes, but this is a faster solution which works from command line, same as `awk` usage. Up to you whether you want to use or not.

Comment: @Sundeep : which part is faster ?

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto not sure what your question is. I don't know how it works internally. I just compared this perl solution ( 0m0.793s) to Ed Morton's awk solution (0m1.070s, after adding `print s`).

Comment: @Sundeep : maybe it's a fast solution within the perl world, but `.79s` for 100-mil of a character isn't fast in the `awk` world. you can see my submissions below

Comment: @Sundeep the object of the exercise wasn't to print a string, it was to create a string in a variable. To compare apples to apples don't add `print s` to my code, modify yours to create a variable that holds the result instead of printing it. If I WAS going to change my code to print a string then you wouldn't add `print s`, you'd change `s = substr(...)` to `print substr(...)`, but again, that's not the point of this question and I'd probably write it differently anyway with intermediate prints rather than accumulating chars in a variable.

Comment: @EdMorton oh ok, thanks for the clarification. For creating variable with a string of `100000000` characters, I get `0m0.071s` with Perl. I get `0m0.136s` with Mawk and `0m0.429s` with Gawk.

Comment: @Sundeep you're welcome. Would you mind including the perl code to create that variable in your question so others can see/use it?

Answer (score -1):

*Is there a better way to repeat a char n times and assign the result to a variable?*

I propose following solution limited to case where n is equal to 2^x and x is integer equal or greater 1. For example to get `x` repeated 32 i.e. 2^5 times

```
awk 'BEGIN{s="x";for(i=1;i<=5;i+=1)s=s s;print s}' emptyfile.txt
```

output

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score -5):

extreme test case benchmark - comparing `python3`'s built-in repeater running on compiled C-code, versus user-level scripting of a different algorithm, generating `152.58 bn` zeros.

```
 Starting point :: length =  4  < "0000" > | time =   0.000000 secs 

 For-Loop # 1 | Lgth-Gain Ratio      6.0x | #-0's :              24. |  0.000036 secs (cum.)
 For-Loop # 2 | Lgth-Gain Ratio     26.0x | #-0's :             624. |  0.000050 secs (cum.)
 For-Loop # 3 | Lgth-Gain Ratio    626.0x | #-0's :         390,624. |  0.000175 secs (cum.)
 For-Loop # 4 | Lgth-Gain Ratio 390626.0x | #-0's : 152,587,890,624. | 21.485092 secs (cum.)

( mawk2 ; )  
 4.38s user 13.69s system 81% cpu 22.226 total

( python3 -c 'print(len("0"*(5**4**2-1)))'; )  
 4.34s user 17.32s system 71% cpu 30.291 total

152587890624



% ( time ( mawk2 '

    function comma(_,__,___,____,_____) {   
    
        if(length(sprintf("%+.f",_))<=(\
          __*=__+=__=__~__)) { 
          return \  
             index(_,".") ?_:_"."   
        }
         ____=CONVFMT;CONVFMT="%.1000g";___=_
         _____="[0-9]"
        gsub("^|$",_____,_____)
         sub("^[^.]+","",___)
         sub("("(_____)")+([.]|$)",",&",_)
        gsub(_____,"&,",_)
         sub("([,]*[.].*)?$",___,_)
         sub("[,]+$",".",_)
         sub("^[ \t]*[+-]?[,]+",\
             substr("-",__==__,_~"^[ \t]*[-]"),_)
      CONVFMT=____;   
      return _ }

   function printProgress(_____) { 

      print sprintf(" For-Loop "\
           "# %d | Lgth-Gain Ratio %8.1fx | "\
           "#-0\47s : %16s | %9s secs (cum.)",
            ++_-_____+!—_,
            (___^-!!___)*(___=length(__)),
            comma(___),timer())
      return fflush() } 

   function timer(_,__,___) { 

      return sprintf("%.*s%.*s%*.*f",
        !(_+=_+=(_=(_=__=___="")~_)+_),
         srand(),
        !(__+=__=--_),___=int((__^=++_)*\
                     +substr(srand(),++_)),
         __%(++_-+-++_),_+=_=(++_+--_)%—_,
        !_TIME0_?(_TIME0_=___)*!__\
            :(___-_TIME0_)/__) 
 } BEGIN {   
        ____=__+=__*=___=__^=(__+=++__)^__;
          gsub("",__,__)
        gsub(".",!__,__)

        print ORS,"Starting point :: length = ",
           ___=length(__=substr(__,__~__,_=4)),
              " < \42"(__)"\42 > | time = " ,
                       timer(), "secs", ORS; 

        for(_____=_;_____;_____--) { 
                  gsub("",__,__) 
            printProgress(_____) } }' )) ;`
    
    sleep 2;

     ( time (python3 -c 'print(len("0"*(5**4**2-1)))' ))|lgp3;
```

UPDATE 1 : generic version of it

depending on which variant of `awk`, it automatically switches to BAU `binary doubler`, and for the `squarer`, the speed gains are so immense it's actually faster to square, then substring than trying to be pin-drop accurate at each level, which inherently slows it down. `_mN` is the binary double, `genZeros` is the `exp-sqr` one

```
mawk2 '
function _mN(__,____,_,___,_____,______){
    return \
    (_=_~_)<+__?(_____=_mN((__-(\
    ______=__%(_+=_)))/_,____,___))___\
    (_____)(______?(___)____:""):__<_?"":____ 

} 
function genZeros(_,__,___,____) {
    if (+_<=+((__=___=____="")<__)) {
        return \
        (-_<+_) ? +__:___;
    } else if (FLG1*(_~"...")) {
        return _mN(_,_<_)
    }
    ____=__+=__*=___=__^=(__+=++__)^__;
    gsub("",__,__)-gsub(".",!__,__)
    if (_<__){ return \
        substr((__)__,_~_,_)
    }; ___=(___=__)___;__="";
    __+=++__+__;
    _-=__*(__=int((_/__)^(--__)^-!!_))*__;
    ___=(__<length(___))\
            ? substr(___,__~__,__) \
       : sprintf("%"(+"")"*.f",__,!__)
           gsub(".",(___)(___)___,___)
    return \
    !_?___:FLG2?\
    sprintf("%"(_<_)"*.f",+_,_)___:_mN(+_,_<_) 

} BEGIN { CONVFMT=\
             OFMT="%.20g"
             FLG1=(+sprintf("%o",-1)<"0x1")
             FLG2=!(sprintf("%d",3E10)%2) 
} { 
    print length(genZeros(3^18)),3^18 }'

387420489 387420489
```

=================================

Doubling each loop is too slow. To get even better performance, you need exponential squaring. how about `88 milli-seconds` :

```
 echo; ( time (gawk -v n=100000000 -Sbe 'BEGIN { 

 CONVFMT=OFMT="%.20g"

 __="x";____="."
  _=10^((___=3)*___)
     gsub(____,__,_)

  while(___--){ 
      gsub(____,_,_) 
  }
  print length(_) }' ) ) | lgp3


( gawk -v n=100000000 -Sbe ; )  

0.07s user 0.01s system 95% cpu 0.088 total
100000000
```

And that's only for `gawk`. For `mawk-2`, it's an unearthly `32 msecs`

```
echo; ( time ( mawk2 -v n=100000000 'BEGIN { CONVFMT=OFMT="%.20g"
   
   __="x";____=".";
   _=10^((___=3)*___)
         gsub(____,__,_)
   while(___--) { 
      gsub(____,_,_) }
  
   print length(_) }' ) ) | lgp3 


( mawk2 -v n=100000000 ; )  
0.01s user 0.02s system 84% cpu 0.032 total
100000000
```

`404 msecs` is all it takes to go from just 1 single copy of "`x`", to nearly ***4.3 billion*** copies of it :

```
 ( time ( mawk2 '
   BEGIN {
       ___=(_+=_+=++_)^(_*_)
        __=length(_=(_="x")(_)_);++___
       
       while(__*__<___) {
           gsub("",_,_)
               __*=++__
           print --__ 
       } 
       print ORS,length(_),ORS  }' ) )

15
255
65535
4294967295

 4294967295

 0.09s user 0.25s system 84% cpu 0.404 total
```

**UPDATE** :

benchmarking generating `25.7 billion` zeros — at this size level, `python3`'s built-in repeater is being left in the dust

```
  echo; (fg && fg && fg ) 2>/dev/null; 
  echo; 
  ( time ( mawk2 '
          BEGIN {   _=_<_
                   __= 4
           while(__—) { 
               gsub("",(_)(_)_,_) 
           }
           print _ }' 
       ) \
         | pvE9 | LC_ALL=C gwc -lc ) | ggXy3 | ecp 
 sleep 1.5
 echo
 ( time ( python3 -c 'print("0"*25710762175)' 
         ) \
 | pvE9 | LC_ALL=C gwc -lc ) | ggXy3 | ecp ; echo 


 
     out9: 23.9GiB 0:00:08 [2.85GiB/s] [2.85GiB/s] [ <=> ]

  ( mawk2 'BEGIN { _=_<_;__=4; while(__--){ gsub("",(_)(_)_,_) };  print _ }'; )  0.79s user 4.72s system 63% cpu 8.729 total
  pvE 0.1 out9  0.54s user 2.93s system 41% cpu 8.435 total
  LC_ALL=C gwc -lc  2.03s user 1.46s system 41% cpu 8.434 total

      1 25710762176

 
     out9: 23.9GiB 0:00:11 [2.17GiB/s] [2.17GiB/s] [ <=> ]
   ( python3 -c 'print("0"*25710762175)'; )  1.24s user 6.84s system 72% cpu 11.076 total
   pvE 0.1 out9  0.56s user 2.80s system 30% cpu 11.075 total
   LC_ALL=C gwc -lc  2.03s user 1.46s system 31% cpu 11.074 total

      1 25710762176
```

UPDATE 2 : (partially unrelated, but to illustrate my thought process)

Once you realize there's a predictable and deterministic pattern to how the pop-count string appears and repeats, you can create the full pop-count string for all `256-bytes sequentially` using only 4-cycles of the `do-while` loop,

without using hardware instructions, or having to go through every byte one-by-one, either in decimal integer bit-string form, in order to create a pop-count string. The one thing that's crucial though, is setting a `CONVFMT` value large enough to avoid scientific notation truncation, since the essence of the function is performing multiple *16-digit* integer adds (getting near `2^53` but never exceeding) ::

```
 <<<''  mawk '

  function initPopCountStr(_,__,
          ___,____,_____,______) {
          # No.# of set:bits per:byte
          #
     __=_=(_<_)(______=___=_~_)
     ______+=++______;
     do {_=\                         
       (__=_)(__+(___=(___)___))
     } while (--______) 
     return \
     (((_=(_)(____=(__+___)(___+__+___))\ 
     ____)(_____=((__+(___+=______=___)))\ 
                    (___+=__+______)))____\
              (_____)_____)(___)(______+___) 
 } BEGIN {
     CONVFMT="%.20g"
 } { 
     print initPopCountStr() }' \
                                 \
 | gsed -zE 's/(.{16})(.{16})/\1:\2\n/g' |nonEmpty|gcat -n|lgp3 4

     1  0112122312232334:1223233423343445
     2  1223233423343445:2334344534454556
     3  1223233423343445:2334344534454556
     4  2334344534454556:3445455645565667

     5  1223233423343445:2334344534454556
     6  2334344534454556:3445455645565667
     7  2334344534454556:3445455645565667
     8  3445455645565667:4556566756676778
```

Or if you prefer no loops at all, and have everything folded in into one fell swoop :

```
 function initPopCountStr(_,__,
         ___,____,_____,______) {
        # No.# of set:bits per:byte 
       # 
 return \   
         \
  (((_=(_=(__=(_=(__=(_=(__=(_=(__=_=(_<_)(______=___=_~_))\
        (__+(___=(___)___)) ))(__+(___=(___)___))))\
        (__+(___=(___)___))))\
        (__+(___=(___)___)))(____=(__+___)(___+__+___))____)\
    (_____=((__+(___+=______=___)))(___+=__+______)))\
             (____)(_____)_____)(___)(______+___)
}
```

---

even the ultra lazy method is only `0.791 secs` :

```
 out9: 95.4MiB 0:00:00 [ 129MiB/s] [ 129MiB/s] [<=> ]

( mawk2 -F= 'NF=+$_+(OFS=$_=$NF)' ORS= <<< '100000000=x'; )  

0.59s user 0.16s system 95% cpu 0.791 total
```

And the *fast* method is **`16 milli seconds`**

```
fg;fg; ( time ( <<< '100000000=x' mawk2 -F= '{
  
     _ = sprintf("%*s",__=int((____=+$(_=\
                     +(___="."))) ^ +(++_/(++_*_))),"")       
         gsub(___,$NF,_)
    do { gsub(___,_,_) 
    
    } while((__*=__)<____)

   print length(_),substr(_,1,31) }' ) ) | gcat -n | lgp3 

   fg: no current job 
   fg: no current job

( mawk2 -F=  <<< '100000000=x'; )  

0.00s user 0.01s system 87% cpu 0.016 total
     1  100000000 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

UPDATE : making **`3,486,784,401`** copies of `"x"` in `0.323 secs`

```
 fg;fg; ( time ( <<< '43046721=x' mawk2 -F= '
        { 
          ________=substr("",+srand()) +substr(srand(),7)
                 _=sprintf("%*s",__=int((___=+$(_=+\
                          (_____=".")))^(++_/(++_*_))),"")
                gsub(_____,$NF,_)
           do { gsub(_____, _, _) } while((__*=__)<___)
        
        print sprintf(" %15.8f GiB | %20.13f",
                     (__=length(_))/8^10, 
                     ((substr("",+srand())+substr(srand(),7))-\
                     (___=________))/(1+4^-24))
        
        print substr(_,1,33)
        CONVFMT=OFMT="%.14g"
                ____=9
        while(--____){ 
          sub(".+","&&&&&&&&&",_)
             
          print sprintf(" %15.8f GiB | %20.13f",
                length(_)/8^10,((substr("",+srand()) +\
                substr(srand(),7))-___)/(1+4^-24)); fflush() } }' ) )  

fg: no current job
fg: no current job

      0.04009038 GiB |      0.0077791213989
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

      0.36081345 GiB |      0.0445649623871
      3.24732103 GiB |      0.3233759403229
     29.22588923 GiB |      3.5619049072266
    263.03300306 GiB |     58.9802551269529
```

Grow it at a different rate and we get :

- **`103 billion`** copies of `"x"` just shy of `17 seconds`

=

```
      0.04304672 x 10^9 |      0.0111348628998
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    0.3013270470 x 10^9 (        301327047)|      0.0563540458679
    2.1092893290 x 10^9 (       2109289329)|      0.2259490489960
   14.7650253030 x 10^9 (      14765025303)|      1.4351949691773
  103.3551771210 x 10^9 (     103355177121)|     16.9313509464274
```

And relatively trivial to adjust it for arbitrary sizes :

```
{m,g}awk '{             # the timer bit is for mawk-2
     CONVFMT = "%.25g"
        OFMT = "%.13f"
    ________ =  substr("", +srand()) + substr(srand(), 7)
           _ = sprintf("%*s", __=int((___= +$(_=\
                     +(_____="."))^ (++_/(++_*_))),"")
    gsub(_____, $NF, _)
    do {
    print ___, gsub(_____, _, _), 
              ((substr("",+srand()) + 
                substr(srand(), 7)) -________)/(1-4^-25)
    
    } while ((__*=__)<___ && __<4^8)
    print ".", length(_)
    print \
    sprintf("\n----------------\n%42.f .%20.13f", 
           (__=length(_))==___ ?__: (__=length(_= sprintf("%.*s",
            ___-__,_)(_))),((substr("", +srand()\
           )+substr(srand(),7))-________) / (1-4^-25))
    
    print substr(_, 1, 19)
}'
```

|

```
( mawk2 -F=  <<< '3987654321=x'; )  

0.20s user 0.55s system 94% cpu 0.799 total

3987654321               251  0.0000970363617
3987654321             63001  0.3465299606323
.                 3969126001
----------------
3987654321        .           0.7496919631958
```

Comment: I downvote obfuscated code.

Comment: try it yourself - it'll actually lead to more efficient programs, as you carefully think through the number of local temp variables you need, which leads to increased repurposing of temp variables. @laune : or are you just upset you never thought of it first ? ( python3 -c 'print(len("0"*4294967295))'; )  0.11s user 0.32s system 99% cpu 0.431 total
4294967295. In fact, mine benchmarked even faster than python3's built-in approach.

Comment: @laune : there's actually no intentional obfuscation of code. I actually write code like that for my own use as well, believe it or not. code obfuscation would be using a trillion layers of redirection and anonymizing like in javascript. alphanumeric variable names are actually a distraction since it prevents you from thinking like the computer does. they're like skiing poles - it's hard to improve your parallel turns when the poles serve only as clutches. My own skills have improved more in last 2 months ever since i started coding like that, versus the past 7 years combined.

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto Webster's defines "to obfuscate" as " to be evasive, unclear, or confusing". Apart from using the underscore as the only character for identifiers thoughout you also obfuscate by setting a variable (i.e., n) without using it, and you create a string of ten times "x" by intricately creating a number with ten digits and the subsequent. replacement of all digits by "x", both is a true hallmark of code obfuscation. Misleading indentation is just a trifling add-on.

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto After making your first code snippet readable I realized that it does only one thing: create a string of 100000000 "x"' using hand-coded values ("xxxxxxxxxx" and 3) to feed the loop. Generally one tries to provide a general solution that works for any time of repetitions - but perhaps this is not iin your line of thinking.

Comment: @laune : actually I've already pre-written the generic solution a long time ago. see my updated post

Comment: @laune : told you i write code like that for myself, regardless of what webster definition you wanna use to make yourself feel better. See of you can figure out what variant+invocation-flag combos of awk that satisfy FLG1 and FLG2

Comment: @laune : ps : also adding another code snippet on how i initialize a pop-count string for all 256-bytes using only 4-cycles of a do-while loop.

Comment: @laune : feel free to replace that "x" with anything you like- concept is the same. 859 mn copies of your username, 425ms : ( time ( mawk2 'BEGIN { _=( ___ =_="laune")( _ ) _ ; ____ ="."; for( __=3 ; __ ; __--) { gsub( _____, _ , _ ); _____=( _____ )_____; print (length( _ )/5) " copies of ["( ___ )"]", substr( _ ,1,50) }}' )) 51 copies of [laune] launelaunelaunelaunelaunelaunelaunelaun…
13107 copies of [laune] launelaunelaunelaunelaunelaunelaune
858993459 copies of [laune] ( mawk2 ; ) 0.10s user 0.26s system 84% cpu 0.425 total. Do u have anything faster 2 propose?