# most efficient way to join array with separators in awk

Tags: performance, awk

In awk scripts, I see several methods used to concatenate an array of strings with a separator, mainly trinary being used in some way, or the separator is changed on the fly. Occasionally `printf`/`sprintf` is used but I won't consider that here as I'd be surprised if the function call is not expensive.

For example, given an awk array `a` of strings, with integer indices from 1 to `max`, and separator `sep`:

**trinary:**

```
j=""
for ( i=1; i<=max; i++ )
    j = ( j ? j sep a[i] : a[i] )
```

**modify:**

```
j=s=""
for ( i=1; i<=max; i++ ) {
    j = j s a[i]
    s = sep
}
```

I have just come up with this method which I don't recall seeing before (ed: from subsequent comments, this turns out to be similar to a method used by [awklib](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tree/awklib/eg/lib/join.awk)):

**mine (for):**

```
j = a[1]
for ( i=1; i<max; ) 
    j = j sep a[++i]
```

Naively, I would assume this to be more efficient as:

- there are no tests other than for the loop counter;
- there are no modifications to the separator; and
- the redundant final test is elided.

Another option I just thought of:

**mine (while):**

```
j=a[i=max]
while (i>1)
    j = a[--i] sep j
```

Running a simple benchmark of `gawk` and `mawk` on a mostly idle Ubuntu 20.04 laptop (9 trials each of 1,000,000 iterations of joining a 64-element array of 50-char strings) gave me:

**gawk**

| algorithm | min | max | median | mean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| trinary | 13.863 | 15.214 | 14.148 | 14.330 |
| modify | 11.052 | 11.926 | 11.360 | 11.468 |
| **mine (for)** | **8.612** | **8.792** | **8.698** | **8.710** |
| mine (while) | 12.267 | 13.263 | 12.591 | 12.706 |

**mawk**

| algorithm | min | max | median | mean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| trinary | 12.406 | 13.299 | 12.827 | 12.806 |
| modify | 12.975 | 13.744 | 13.085 | 13.294 |
| mine (for) | 11.641 | 12.397 | 12.233 | 12.151 |
| **mine (while)** | **8.400** | **9.083** | **8.693** | **8.693** |

`busybox awk` is much less performant. Using 100,000 iterations:

| algorithm | min | max | median | mean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| trinary | 11.004 | 12.284 | 11.784 | 11.605 |
| modify | 11.708 | 12.628 | 11.879 | 12.071 |
| mine (for) | 10.695 | 11.642 | 10.776 | 11.021 |
| **mine (while)** | **9.244** | **10.167** | **9.409** | **9.549** |

`original-awk` is faster than busybox in this situation. Using 250,000 iterations:

| algorithm | min | max | median | mean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| trinary | 12.750 | 13.525 | 12.840 | 13.014 |
| modify | 13.105 | 13.778 | 13.942 | 13.572 |
| mine (for) | 11.831 | 12.543 | 12.710 | 12.281 |
| **mine (while)** | **10.730** | **10.854** | **11.466** | **11.032** |

I guessed my second method might be even faster due to not needing to dereference `max` in the loop but, intriguingly, although it runs noticably faster than the other algorithms in most implementations, it runs poorly in `gawk`, where my first method is the clear winner.

Are there even better methods?

Is there a best idiom for awk join?

---

My benchmark code was just:

```
for v in gawk mawk "busybox awk" original-awk; do
    for m in 1 2 3 4; do
        echo ::: $v $m :::
        for n in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do
            time </dev/null $v -f aw$m-${v:0:1}
        done
        echo
    done
done
```

**aw3-b:** (others are similar)

```
BEGIN {
    a[ 1] = "a[ 1]a[ 1]a[ 1]a[ 1]a[ 1]a[ 1]a[ 1]a[ 1]a[ 1]a[ 1]"
    a[ 2] = "a[ 2]a[ 2]a[ 2]a[ 2]a[ 2]a[ 2]a[ 2]a[ 2]a[ 2]a[ 2]"
    # ... more lines ...
    a[63] = "a[63]a[63]a[63]a[63]a[63]a[63]a[63]a[63]a[63]a[63]"
    a[64] = "a[64]a[64]a[64]a[64]a[64]a[64]a[64]a[64]a[64]a[64]"
    max=64
    sep=FS

    for(n=1; n<=100000; n++) {
        j=a[1]
        for (i=1;i<max;)
            j = j sep a[++i]
    }
}
```

Comment: See how gawk suggests it: https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tree/awklib/eg/lib/join.awk -- this corresponds to your method.

Comment: re: the "descending" method: perhaps gawk has some optimizations for _appending_ to a string, and this method needs to rewrite the whole string for each iteration.

Comment: @glennjackman yes, that was my immediate thought too. thanks for pointer to code - looks like my idea's not stupid :-)

Comment: bizarrely, with gawk, rewriting as `j=a[1]; for(i=2;i<=max;i++) j = j sep a[i]` per the awklib code increases runtime to ~10s

Comment: Your third solution doesn't handle the case of an empty array. You can add another test to guard the initial assignment.

Comment: @laune It appears that `j=a[1]` is sufficient! If `a[1]` didn't exist, it just returns the empty string anyway. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
j = a[1]
for ( i=2; i<=max; i++ ) 
    j = j sep a[i]
```

is the clearest and most common approach so IMHO it's what should be used even if a tiny performance improvement could be squeezed out of a slightly less clear script.

The time when you typically see a ternary being used is when printing the contents of the array as:

```
for ( i=1; i<=max; i++ ) 
    printf "%s%s", a[i], (i<max ? OFS : ORS)
```

instead of the slightly more efficient but lengthier and requiring the printf formatting string and associated data values to be duplicated before the loop for the first index and inside the loop for all of the other indices:

```
printf "%s", a[1]
for ( i=2; i<=max; i++ ) 
    printf "%s%s", OFS, a[i]
print ""
```

Just yesterday I was surprised by a huge performance improvement using a recursive descent function instead of a loop, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68389244/1745001, so I thought I'd give that a try but it failed miserably:

```
$ head -50 tst*.awk
==> tstLoop.awk <==
BEGIN {
    max = 64
    for (i=1; i<=max; i++) {
        a[i] = sprintf("%50s",i)
    }
    for (n=1; n<=100000; n++) {
        j = a[1]
        for (i=2; i<=max; i++) {
            j = j OFS a[i]
        }
    }
}

==> tstRec.awk <==
function join(i){
    if( i == 1 ) return a[i]
    return join(i-1) OFS a[i]
}

BEGIN {
    max = 64
    for (i=1; i<=max; i++) {
        a[i] = sprintf("%50s",i)
    }
    for (n=1; n<=100000; n++) {
        j = join(max)
    }
}
```

```
$ time awk -f tstLoop.awk

real    0m2.596s
user    0m2.561s
sys     0m0.030s
```

```
$ time awk -f tstRec.awk

real    0m3.743s
user    0m3.733s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Comment: Any loop can be written using a recursive function. - Here, nothing is gained by the recursion: you still need max-1 concatenations. But you add max function calls and max-1  hidden string store operations. - Your test compares inline code in tstLoop to a function in tstRec but the additional calls don't make much difference.

Comment: @laune Yeah, I understand that now, thanks. When I saw [your code yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68371275/how-to-generate-string-with-a-char-repeated-for-n-times/68389244#68389244) I thought it meant there was some implementation detail about comparisons that made recursion faster but of course that's not really the case as shown above and clear now given the explanation added to your answer.

Comment: As pointed out in the question comments, I appear to just have rediscovered the awklib version (modulo minor tweak). Ho hum.

Comment: I just noticed that this method (also "mine (for)") creates the `a[1]` element if it did not already exist, which could cause unexpected behaviour if `a` is used again later

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it is better in the sense that the overall performance is in any way better than the for loop, but it is more clean for regular record processing use cases where the array is implicitly given from the record numbers:

```
awk 'FNR==1 {printf $1} FNR>1 {printf " "$1} END {printf "\n"}'
```

I understand that this is not what the Author really asked for, but it will likely be what people finding this post are really looking for.

Comment: if you wanna join full lines instead of just `$1`, then this may be more streamlined : `{m,n,g}awk -- --NF RS='^$' FS='\n'`

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE 2 : quick note on **joining direction**

I've observed that `gawk` and `mawk` each have a preferred joining direction that's **much much** faster than the other direction (as in roughly 1 order of magnitude), but the directions are also reversed between the 2 :

> - `mawk` : much faster when continuously ***pre***pend-ing to the string
> - `gawk` : much faster when continuously **append**-ing to the string

================================================================

@**jhnc** : i'm not too sure how well your suggested method scales :

- `75,369 rows` | `13.3 MB` `utf-8` `.txt` file,

  splitting and join by `\n`

```
echo; fg;fg; f="${m2m}"; xxh128sum "${f}" | ecp; echo; 
sleep 1; 
( time ( pvE0 < "${f}" | 
       LC_ALL=C mawk2x 'BEGIN { FS=RS="^$"; OFS=ORS=_="" 
                        } END { __=split($-_,___,____="\n"); 
                                print \
                                fastjoin(___,____,!_,__) }' ) |
pvE9 ) | xxh128sum| lgp3 | ecp
sleep 1
( time ( pvE0 < "${f}" | 

  LC_ALL=C mawk2 'BEGIN { FS=RS="^$"; OFS=ORS=_="" 
                  } END { __=split($-_,___,____="\n"); 
                          _____=___[__]_^=_<_;
                          while (_<__) { _____=___[--__](____)_____ }
                          print _____ }' ) | 
pvE9 ) | xxh128sum | lgp3 | ecp

fg: no current job
fg: no current job
 
c023ca75edcabbdd1253859a27e08c5f  /………./m2vid_main.txt     
 

      in0: 13.3MiB 0:00:00 [ 138MiB/s] [ 138MiB/s] [=============>] 100%            
     out9: 13.3MiB 0:00:00 [97.7MiB/s] [97.7MiB/s] [<=> ]

( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${f}" | LC_ALL=C mawk2x ; )
```

`0.13s user 0.04s system 109% cpu` **`0.159`** `total`

```
c023ca75edcabbdd1253859a27e08c5f  stdin


      in0: 13.3MiB 0:00:00 [2.27GiB/s] [2.27GiB/s] [========>] 100%            
     out9: 13.3MiB 0:00:38 [ 356KiB/s] [ 356KiB/s] [<=>]
( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${f}" | LC_ALL=C mawk2 ; )
```

`15.51s user 22.63s system 99% cpu` **`38.152`** `total`

```
c023ca75edcabbdd1253859a27e08c5f  stdin
```

For a 2nd test file a few more orders of magnitude in size :

- `8.12 mn rows` | `153MB` `ASCII`-only `.txt` file,

  split and join by `\n`

```
699ddf5bda2530a07d9651fe0b43a624  /……/m2map_main.txt     
 
  8125949 160950671 160950671     /……/m2map_main.txt
 

      in0:  153MiB 0:00:00 [1.10GiB/s] [1.10GiB/s] [============>] 100%            
     out9:  153MiB 0:00:01 [ 108MiB/s] [ 108MiB/s] [<=> ]
( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${f}" | LC_ALL=C mawk2x ; )
```

`1.09s user 0.33s system 98% cpu` **`1.438`** `total`

```
699ddf5bda2530a07d9651fe0b43a624  stdin

 
# it's still running after 23 mn 10 secs, so I halted it
 
      in0:  153MiB 0:00:00 [2.86GiB/s] [2.86GiB/s] [============>] 100%            
     out9: 0.00 B **0:23:10** [0.00 B/s] [0.00 B/s] [<=>
```

What I realized was that for *really* large inputs, regardless of which `awk` flavor, neither pure linear or pure recursion is ideal, but a combination of both is closer to optimal :

```
  —- fewer than, say, 100-200 bytes, then join them linearly

  —- otherwise, keep recursing downwards
```

UPDATE 1 ::

```
9.94 secs to split out a 12.49 mn cell array then join it back into a single 
1.85 GB string should at least be semi-respectable speed for scripting code
```

|

```
    {m,g}awk '
     BEGIN {
     1      FS=RS = "^$"
     1       ____ = "="
     1      _____ = ORS
     1       split( ORS = OFS = _="",___)
    } END {
     1      print six4join(___,_____,!_,_=\
                     split($+_,___,(_____)))
     1      printf(\
               "\n\n\n %.f \n\n\n",_) >("/dev/stderr")
    }
524287  function six4join(__,_____,_,____,___,______)
        {
524287      if ((______="") == ___) { # 1
     1          for (______ in __)  { break  }
     1          if(!(______ in __)) { return }
            }
524287         _=    _!=(______="")? +_    :+_ in __?+_:++_
524287      ____= ____!= ______    ? +____ : length(__)-!_
524287       ___=  ___!= ______    ? +___  : ____-_

524287      if((______*=______+=++______)^--______<___ || ___<______) {
262143          return ______<___\
                ? six4join(__,_____,_,___=_+int(___/--______), ___-_)\
                  (_____) six4join(__,_____,++___,____,____-___) \
                : +___ == --______\
                ? __[_](___=_____) __[--____]___ __[++____] \
                : +___ <-___ ?"":__[_] (-___<+___ ?(_____) __[____]:""))
            }
262144          ___ = __[_]
262144       ______+= ++______
262144         ____ = (_____) substr("", _____=____)

1746372     while((_____-_++) % ______) {
1746372         ___ = (___)____ __[_]
            }

1310720     while(_<+_____) {
1310720         ___ = (___)____ __[_++]____ __[_++]____ __[_++]____\
                    __[_++]____ __[_++]____ __[_++]____ __[_++]____ __[_++]
            }

262144      return ___
        }
```

`f9d2e18d22eb58e5fc2173863cff238e  stdin`

```
rows = 12494275. | UTF8 chars = 1285316715. | bytes = 1983544693.


   in0:  295MiB 0:00:00 [2.88GiB/s] [2.88GiB/s] [>] 15% ETA 0:00:00
   in0: 1.85GiB 0:00:00 [3.00GiB/s] [3.00GiB/s] [===>] 100%
  out9: 1.65GiB 0:00:09 [2.85GiB/s] [ 174MiB/s] [ <=> ]
  out9: 1.85GiB 0:00:09 [ 190MiB/s] [ 190MiB/s] [ <=> ]
  

 12494276   # this figure is always expected to be 
            # 1 more than row count whenever 
            # there is a trailing `\n`

( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${f}" | LC_ALL=C mawk2 ; )
```

`5.42s user 4.22s system 96% cpu` **`9.942`** `total`

`f9d2e18d22eb58e5fc2173863cff238e  stdin`